# How to parse data from a class with the same name?

Tags: android, html-parsing, jsoup

I use jsoup library for parse data from some sites. For example:
If i need parse data from class

```
<div class="information"> Something info </div>
```

i write:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
Elements i = doc.getElementsByClass("information");
```

And after i get result in textview. All the good.

But! If such classes 2 or 3 and they have the same name, but information in each class different.

For example:

```
<div class="information"> About cat </div>
<div class="information"> About dog </div>
<div class="information"> About world </div>
```

What me then do? If i do that:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
Elements i = doc.getElementsByClass("information");
Elements j = doc.getElementsByClass("information");
Elements k = doc.getElementsByClass("information");
```

Variable i,j and k will be contain information

```
About cat
About cat
About cat
```

But i need:

```
About cat
About dog
About world
```

And finally question! How to realize transition to the next class for each variable. What me add in code except `getElementsByClass`?

I hope clearly described the problem.

Comment: Well, how do you intend to distinguish your three `div.information`-s? (How do you know that `i` should be `About cat` and `j` should be `About dog`, and not vice versa?)

Comment: i,j and k this is variable, which i use in textview. Just i have three textview and each shows value from class "information". But i dont know,how make transition to next class inside my code.

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate through the returned Elements. eg:

```
Elements els = doc.getElementsByClass("information");
for (Element e : els) {
// Do something with e (eg. e.text())
}
```

Edit: Just to clarify, the Elements returned by getElementsByClass is a list containing all the elements you want. In your code, i, j, and k should all be the same.

Comment: For example: How would you implement parsing weather yahoo. There is also a class "temperature" weather for today and tomorrow the same.